# How to add two fields instead of one on click of link to add fields in nested form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have used gem 'nested_form', '~> 0.3.2' with rails 4, i have to add two fields on click of link_to_add helper method of nested form? How will i customize the javascript of nested form to add for this specific scenario?

Comment: Add related part of the javascript to your question, so that others can update it.

Comment: Do you mean you need to add 2 different associated models under a single form.. or do you mean you need to add 2 fields in a single associated model inside your form, or do you mean something else entirely?  Please clarify your question, and provide the form code.

Comment: I have to add 2 fields in single associated model inside my form.In existing nested form when u add nested fields it gives you one set of form of association but in my scenario i have to add two fields.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using jQuery:

```
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event) {
    for (var n = 1; n; n--) {
        if ($('.fields').length < 2) {
            event.field.clone().insertAfter(event.field);
        }
    }
});
```